# Custom TransactionScope

Tags: .net, database, transactions, relational-database

TransactionScope has several restrictions:
1. IsolationLevel can't change during transaction
2. Nested transaction scopes are not really what we know as nested transactions

Is it possible to write custom TransactionScope to workaround these restrictions or are they integrated into core of System.Transactions and can't be changed?

**Upd.** If not why do people create custom TransactionScopes? What problems does it allow to solve?

Comment: Re 2 - how do you mean? They are *exactly* what I would expect from DTC transactions... or is your intention to rollback an inner transaction but commit an outer transaction? (which you can't do)

Comment: But what if I want to emulate nested transactions when I can rollback inner transaction without rollbacking root transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your 2nd point (and reading the comment); indeed, the "one fail, everything rolls back immediately" is an inherent part of DTC; the entire outer transaction is the atomic unit. You *might* be able to use some regular SQL transactions *inside* the DTC transaction, but to be honest that is making things complex...

My suggestion:

- either write the SQL to *succeed* (i.e. on rollback if something gets very ill; not just for convenience of experimental queries)
- or: don't use DTC

and I prefer the first, as rollback is expensive (commit is cheap).

(I don't know definitively for your first point, but I *believe* that is pretty stone-like)